# How to auto select on radio button with value form database

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have **Update** function and this update data like Sex. Male or Female. 
But I didn't know how to choose automatically (auto-check) form database on update form. it's my blade view. btw it's on table **users**

```
<div class="item form-group">
                    <label for="jenis_kelamin" class="control-label col-md-3">Jenis Kelamin <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">


                        <td>
                        <label> Laki-Laki<input type="radio"  name="jenis_kelamin" value="L" checked>
                        </label>
                       </td>


                        <td>

                        <label> Perempuan
                          <input type="radio"  name="jenis_kelamin" value="P">
                        </label>
                       </td>



                        @error('jenis_kelamin')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

on database my value just L and P. how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for equality

```php
<div class="item form-group">
    <label for="jenis_kelamin" class="control-label col-md-3">Jenis Kelamin <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">


        <td>
        <label> Laki-Laki<input type="radio" @if($user->your_enum_attribute == 'L') checked @endif name="jenis_kelamin" value="L" checked>
        </label>
        </td>


        <td>
        <label> Perempuan
            <input type="radio" @if($user->your_enum_attribute == 'P') checked @endif name="jenis_kelamin" value="P">
        </label>
        </td>



        @error('jenis_kelamin')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```